# Way to create a PO against Sales Order Item in netsuite

Tags: c#, netsuite

One of the sales order Items of a Sale Order shows a link to create a PO.  It has a PO Vendor associated with the line item (a sales order Item).  I am looking for a way to programmatically create a PO against the sales order item.

There is a property called "createPo" and "createPoSpecified".  I don't know how to work them in order to create a PO linked to that specific sales order item.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The line items that are `special order` or `drop ship items` , NetSuite automatically creates POs for them on save (provided the SO is approved and a `preferred vendor` is specified for that item in subsidiary in which the Sales Order falls, or else at least one preferred vendor has been specified for non-one world accounts).

For items that are not marked as drop ship or special order item, you will need to explicitly set `Create PO` field as `Drop Shipment` or `Special Order`

Answer (score 1):

for each line in SalesOrder.Items, set [CREATE PURCHASE ORDER] to Special Order so Netsuite will create PO automatically

Answer (score 0):

you can also set those values with a script. as outlined in the SuiteAwnsers "[Setting the Create PO field to null via SuiteScript](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35911/kw/set%20create%20PO)"

Here is a sample script I have tested (you will have to add the "if" conditions)

```html
function beforeSubmit(type)
{
     var count = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    for (i=1; i<= count; i++)
    {
        var currentContext = nlapiGetContext();

        //setting of 'createpo' field only happens when the script is triggered via User Interface
        //add other if conditions here, if needed
       // 'createpo' values are Null, 'DropShip', or 'SpecOrd'
        if((currentContext.getExecutionContext() == 'userinterface'))
        {
            nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'createpo', i, 'DropShip');
        }
    }
}
```